# Linux Printing Authentication in cli

Tags: command-line, printing, authentication

In GUI you can authenticate (username AND password) before printing (Require by the terminal printer) but I can't do the same via command line interface (Spent all morning searching for how)

This is the authentication interface that comes with the GUI:
[image: This is the authentication interface that comes with the GUI].

I use lpr

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu @New1997, Please edit your question and add the command with which you try to print from CLI

Comment: The command used to print shouldn't matter.

Comment: That is the thing, I want to know if there is any command which allows me the authenticate and printing to the network printer